# How do I run code a percentage of time

Tags: php

In my script I want to run certain code a certain percent of the time, I've looked around StackOverflow and found the code below.  It runs the code 33% of the time, what do I need to modify to get it to run 55% and 70% of the time?

```
$max = 27;

for($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++){
if($i % 3 == 0){
        call_function_here();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I might ask, why would you want to do this?

Comment: like i need different things to be shown a certain amount of times in like a reward system it can show promo codes etc

Comment: Will using a random number generation with a limit not work? Or I suppose you could round :)

Comment: Random number generators are only random for the instant that they generate a number. Meaning if you generate a random number 10 times, you are just as likely to get 4 every time as you are to getting 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10. Therefore, you cannot depend on your random number generator to do something like this. It's actually (gag) more reliable to give a user a coupon based on their userId % 100 to get the percentage he wants, pseudo-randomly.

Comment: What? Did my head just fall off? :) If you have ever heard of something called the gamblers fallacy, it explicitly states why random number generation will work. On any given time I choose from a list of 1-10 randomly. I will have a 10% chance of getting a number that I have chosen. So, if I want a 30 percent change, I would be ok in just allowing 3 numbers regardless of the previous number.

Comment: @JaredDrake I think the issue is that there must be an amount guaranteed. Using random numbers means that you cannot guarantee that at least X will pass.

Comment: @arxanas lol Now, that you word it that way. I see. Sorry, for the gambler's fallacy argument. :)

Comment: @Vic - yes, the ordered list 1-10 is just as probable as 10 4's in a row, however your other statements do not follow from this.  Giving a user a coupon based on their user ID would make no sense, IDs aren't (generally) random, and they don't change over time.  Using a session ID would probably be fine, if you wanted something more consistent than a random number per request, but most session IDs are just random strings anyways.

Comment: @dimo414 Hence my "gag" comment. I wasn't actually recommending you use the user id, just saying that it is "better" than the random number generator. At my workplace, to accomplish a goal not quite entirely like yours but similar, we store the current "iteration" in memcache and act upon it when appropriate. Example, for each customer that comes to our website, we increment a particular counter index and store it. And when that value matches some particular rule, the necessary action is taken.

Comment: @Vic - my primary objection was to the statements "Random number generators are only random for the instant that they generate a number." and "Therefore, you cannot depend on your random number generator to do something like this." - neither are true.  You may have meant to describe *randomness without replacement* but that wasn't a requirement of OP's question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a random number generator and test that its result is less than (or greater than, doesn't matter) the amount you're targeting for.

```
function percentChance($chance){
  // Notice we go from 0-99 - therefore a 100% $chance is always larger
  $randPercent = mt_rand(0,99);
  return $chance > $randPercent;
}

...

if(percentChance(30)){
  // 30% of page loads will enter this block
}

if(percentChance(100)){
  // All page loads will enter this block
}

if(percentChance(0)){
  // No chance this block will ever be entered
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the amount chosen must be constant, you can do this:

```
$max = 27;
$num_selections = round(27 * (55 / 100));
$keys = array_rand($max, $num_selections);
for ($keys as $key) {
    // Do something with the chosen key
}
```